# Changing my list image only works if I do it as internal css?

Tags: html, css

I discovered I have issues getting list images to change and went ahead and created a whole blank playground to try and get this right. Spent hours trying to get it, finally just threw a tantrum and put the code in internally....and it works. But it won't as a class or id selector in an external style sheet. I don't...understand. Help? Help me understand?

My HTML

```
<ul class="custom"> This list is to prove a point.
  <li class="custom2">
    This point is that I can make this code work.
    </li>
  </ul>
```

My CSS

```
.custom ul {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 list-style: none;
}

.custom2 li{
 list-style: none;
 background: url('leafstem.png') no-repeat top left;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 4px 0 4px 20px;
 list-style: none;
}
```

Internal CSS that worked

```
<ul style="margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none;"> This list is to prove a point.
  <li style="list-style: none;
  background: url('leafstem.png') no-repeat top left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 4px 0 4px 20px;
  list-style: none;
  }">
    This point is that I can make this code work.
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: is the external style sheet in a different folder than the HTML? if so the problem could be simply referencing your image in the correct folder.

Comment: It would be helpful if you described in exactly what way it _wasn't_ working before you got it working-- basically, what was the expected behavior and what was the actual behavior.  This context will help the community in providing you with useful guidance.

Comment: It simply didn't work before; did nothing. The list pretended I had added no code. It didn't even respond to the list-style:none, and displayed a circle. I guess the info helps but in my brain "didn't work" meant flat out didn't work, haha! Noted for the future.

Comment: were you calling the CSS file correctly?

Comment: Can you show the code from how you had it before where you were importing an external CSS file?

Comment: Verified that path, that doesn't seem to be it either.

Comment: Added the working code.

Comment: I've gotten in the habit of hitting F12 in the browser to bring up the developer console, then clicking the Select Element tool and then clicking on the element where you're expecting to see your CSS. Then in the Styles section of the console you can see what CSS is or isn't being applied, or if it's being overridden by something else. Also this CSS selectors reference still helps me https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is how you are naming the selectors in your CSS. When you use the selector `.custom ul`, it is going to find `ul` tags that are **INSIDE** of an element with the `.custom` class. Same thing with the `.custom2 li` selector. This is looking for `li` tags **INSIDE** of an element with `.custom2` class.

The reason it's working when you do inline styling is because you are not referencing the incorrectly selected classes. You are adding the `style="";` directly to the element.

```css
.custom {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.custom2 {
    list-style: none;
    background: url('data:image/jpeg;base64,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') no-repeat top left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 4px 0 4px 20px;
    list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="custom"> This list is to prove a point.
    <li class="custom2">
        This point is that I can make this code work.
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Ding ding, silly mistake that took 2 days to solve. Thanks so much!